# Driving a Bar-graph LED Block With a Range of HV

Tags: led, operational-amplifier, analog, diodes, level-shifting

I'm aware that it's possible to use the voltage drop of diodes to act as a step barrier for a rough ADC(?), as is done here (http://www.instructables.com/id/9-Channel-pure-analog-graphic-equalizer/). However, I'd like to drive a bar of LEDs as a voltage meter for a charging capacitor bank. How should I handle level-shifting the capacitor output for the array of LEDs? I'd imagine I'd use an opamp in a positive-feedback setup with very low gain. However, I'm not sure how to efficiently protect the opamp-- I intend to use high-voltage capacitors. Should I connect the capacitor directly to the opamp? Would that kill it? If so, what should I use?

Comment: ...what is "high voltage" here? Hundreds? Thousands? Tens of Thousands? Hundreds of Thousands? Megavolts?

Comment: Hundreds of volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large value resistors making a voltage divider to shift the level (or, you know, divide it), and the hoary old **[LM3914 dot bar display driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf)** which is still in production (perhaps unlike its old friends LM3915 and LM3916, at a quick look of what's in stock - well, digi-key claims to have all 3, so maybe that's better now) - made for the job.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsRkuz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust values to suit your unspecified high voltage. On a quick scan of the datasheet to refresh my memory, you should scale down to 12V or less. Choose resistors that will take it without flashover/tracking, or use enough in series to handle that problem.

Comment: Alright. Is there really no more efficient way to do this, though? I'd imagine that, with high-value resistors, not much current would be drawn, but it seems like there would be other ways that are more efficient still. (This is more for educational purposes than practical-- the capacitor charging setup is quick-and-dirty anyway.)

Comment: Don't imagine. Do the math. 1 MΩ at 1000 V is 1 mA and 1 W. 10 would be a 0.1W, but might also make the input current of the 3914 matter. The divider also serves the very useful purpose of draining the capacitor when the power is off, which is the sort of thing that can  save you from a shocking experience. At merely hundreds of volts you could add a lot of complexity with a high voltage MOSFET driving the divider at some low duty cycle into a "sample and hold" circuit if a lousy watt or less is going to break your HV supply's heart.

Comment: For quick-and-dirty you buy a $6 meter at Harbor Freight or ebay and find out if its 1000V DC scale rating is truthful or optimistic. Keep the receipt in case you need to return it due to optimism

Comment: Ok, thanks for the perspective. I really don't need much other than this. Answer approved.